# how to access has_many models that is created in before clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, factory-bot

There is a `Company` class that `has_many` `QuarterValue`, and I have a RSpec test for it.

```
  let(:company) { Company.create }
  describe 'company has many quarter values' do
    before do
      10.times { create(:quarter_value, company: company) }
    end
    it 'has 10 quarter values' do
      expect(company.quarter_values.count).to eq(10)
    end
  end
```

The test passes. My question is when I put `binding.pry` just above the `expect` matcher I can't access `company.quarter_values`, that returns empty array `[]`.

How can I access `has_many` models object in `RSpec` test by using `binding.pry`?

#### spec/factories.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :company do
    sequence(:code) { |n| n + 1000 }
  end
  factory :quarter_value do
    company
  end
end
```

Comment: What happens if you do a `company.reload`?

Comment: I made an app to test this and duplicated everything given the provided information and cannot replicate. When I binding pry above the expect and then in my console put ```company.quarter_values``` it returns all 10 records ... not an empty array. which is expected but doesn't jive with what you're saying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to modify your code to look like this:

```
let(:company) { Company.create }
describe 'company has many quarter values' do
  before do
    10.times { create(:quarter_value, company: company) }
    company.reload
  end
  it 'has 10 quarter values' do
    expect(company.quarter_values.count).to eq(10)
  end
end
```

The company variable you created at the start has no knowledge that it has been given any `quarter_values`. 
You need to call `company.reload` to update company with the new relations it was given because that instance of the `Company` model wasn't involved in `create(:quarter_value, company: company)`

Answer (score 2):

You should [`reload`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/reload) the `company` object in either `before` block or inside the `pry` session, while debugging.

It

> Reloads the attributes of this object from the database.